# Update User details endpoint returns 405, "error": "Method Not Allowed",

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, crud

I'm trying to update the detail of an existing user in the member table but when I tried to test the endpoint using postman it returned a `405, "error": "Method Not Allowed",`. I tried to find an existing user by id and update the details so that JPA will automatically save it to the database but it return this error

Member

```
@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
 private String firstName;

 @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
 private String lastName;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "nationality_id", nullable = false)
 private Country nationality;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "country_of_residence_id", nullable = false)
 private Country countryOfResidence;

 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name ="date_of_birth", nullable = false, updatable = false)
 private Date dateOfBirth;

 @Column(name ="current_job_title", nullable = false)
 private String currentJobTitle;

 @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
 private String emailAddress;

 @Column(name ="phone_number", nullable = false)
 private String phoneNumber;

 @Column(name ="password", nullable = false)
 private String password;

 @Column(name ="avatar")
 private String avatar;

 @CreationTimestamp
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 @Column(name = "created_on", updatable = false, nullable = false)
 private Date createdOn;

 @UpdateTimestamp
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 @Column(name = "updated_on", nullable = false)
 private Date updatedOn;
```

Service

```
public interface UpdateMemberService {

   ResponseEntity<Member> getMember(long id, Member member);

}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UpdateMemberServiceImpl implements UpdateMemberService {

    @Autowired
    private UpdateMemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Member> getMember(long id, Member member) {

        Member getMember = memberRepository.findById(id).get();

        getMember.setFirstName(member.getFirstName());
        getMember.setLastName(member.getLastName());
        getMember.setNationality(member.getNationality());
        getMember.setCountryOfResidence(member.getCountryOfResidence());
        getMember.setDateOfBirth(member.getDateOfBirth());
        getMember.setCurrentJobTitle(member.getCurrentJobTitle());
        getMember.setEmailAddress(member.getEmailAddress());
        getMember.setPassword(member.getPassword());
        getMember.setAvatar(member.getAvatar());
        getMember.setActive(member.getActive());
        Member updateMember = memberRepository.save(getMember);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updateMember);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UpdateMemberController {

    @Autowired
    private UpdateMemberService memberService;

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Member> updateDetails(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, @RequestBody Member member){
        return memberService.getMember(id, member);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about the exact error you are getting? What do you mean by 'connection error'? Is Postman not able to call the API or the API/code is not able to connect to the database?

Comment: "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/update/1"

Comment: Can you kindly take a look at my code?

Comment: try to check the logging in the console. If there is no logging - try to turn it [on](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) Then do the request again and check the detailed error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you actually debug your code to find out where the failure is.

If, as I suspect, you are not calling the service properly (eg POST instead of PUT), then you won't hit a breakpoint in, say, your controller at all.

If you do hit a breakpoint in your code, look to see where the failure is. If your client calls the service with an id of 1, does a row exist in the database with an id of 1?